# Find the representation of solutions of $x^2+5y^2=z^2$ when $\gcd(x,y）=1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I want to show that for $x^2+5y^2=z^2$ and $\gcd(x,y）=1$, there are 2 cases:

1. $x$ is odd and $y$ is even:

   then $x=\pm(r^2+5s^2),~y=2rs,~z=r^2+5s^2$
2. $x$ is even and $y$ is odd:

   then $x=\pm(2r^2+2rs-2s^2),~y=2rs+s^2,~z=2r^2+2rs+3s^2$

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The solutions to $x^2+5=y^2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730001/the-solutions-to-x25-y2) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E2%2B5y%5E2%3Dz%5E2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cgcd(x%2Cy)%3D1%24&p=1). Note the second part of this other question asks about solving it over rationals, with the [accepted answer](/a/730021) explaining it's equivalent to solving $x^2+5z^2=y^2$ over co-prime integers, and explains how to do that.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you so much but maybe I need more information to complete the problem

Comment: Gang men, you can search this site next time, since many people have written very detailed solutions for such Diophantine equations.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for you knidness and I have collected the site